# Capture excel file attributes during SSIS import

Tags: ssis, attributes, blob, xlsx

I need to import an excel file (xlsx) and write the file to a blob field and also capture  some file attributes during the import: created date, update date

Does SSIS 2010 support this process?  Can  someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Google is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [File Properties Task](http://filepropertiestask.codeplex.com/) - it's free and very easy in use.